# Understanding the meaning of "a beat"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

I've come across some phrases with the word "beat" while reading a book. And though I looked it up in the dictionary, I failed  to explain them by myself. I collected those "mysterious" phrases here:

> New York Department of —what? After half **a beat** of confusion, I
>   snatched up the phone. “Hello?”
>
> “Are you saying that things are not okay for you at your grandparents’
>   home?” said Dave, without missing **a beat**.
>
> <..> Dave (who chuckled, but awkwardly, and always **a beat** too
>   late), he liked to laugh <..>
>
> “Oh,  ” said Mrs. Barbour, after **a beat** or two of surprise.
>
> “I’m sorry,  ” I said, **a beat** too late— <..>

It seems to me that "a beat" means "a moment" in all those cases (according to the context), but (2), in which it might mean "a piece of information" or "not losing the rhytm of speech" or whatever (?? I'm not  sure). But all in all, I've never heard of such usage of the word "beat" and so that I have some doubts. However, someone probably could help me to understand them.

Thank you for any piece af advice!

Comment: You are essentially correct; 'a beat' as used in your examples is an extremely short period of time. Generally, the implied period is shorter than that implied by 'a moment'; the latter is usually interpreted to be a small number of seconds; the former is always less than a second.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Thank you for your response, Jeff! But the funny thing is that this meaning is actually not presented in 2-3 dictionaries I explored (Lingvo, McMillan, Oxford online), I agree, that "beat of the heart" (that is one of the popular meanings in all dictionaries) is similar to some extent, but honestly, this sort of thing possibly deserves to have an extra example...

Comment: This meaning comes from music. If a song is in 4/4 time it has 4 beats to a bar. If you tap your fingers to a piece of music, a beat is the time between taps - and obviously is a different amount of time for different bits of music.

Comment: @simonatrcl Thank you very much, it was crystal clear!

Comment: I think the *first* example is clumsy / unusual, and the last three are all either mistakes, or deliberately quirky misuses (***a beat too late*** is obviously just riffing off the idiomatic standard ***a bit too late***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  thank you, but I really doubt that Donna Tartt suffers from  clumsiness of speech. You can find them all in her "The Goldflinch", btw, if it's somehow interesting to you  or you may want to have a look.

Comment: If you're that much into "literature", what on earth are you doing asking such a trivial question about metaphoric meaning here on ELL? Okay - I'll call that first example a "quirkily amusing stylistic choice" if you like. And remember the target readership is *competent native speakers*, not *people trying to learn English*. It's certainly not a vocabulary choice that non-native speakers should plan to incorporate into their own utterances.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, firstly,  I made that remark just in case you thought I could've picked up those phrases somewhere from foreigners or those natives, who might use them in some weird or simply inappropriate manner. I also said nothing about how experienced I am in "literature", as you put it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Secondly, I asked the question because I had one whatever silly it was, though now I wonder how grand it must be to be *the competent native speaker* while mere mortals are *trying to learn* couple of ridiculous things. And certainly, It is a double pleasure for me to let you feel that pleasing contrast.  And lastly, thank you for your extra advice, even though I didn't ask for that particular one.  I'm sure it will prove both useful and encouraging.

Comment: I must confess that when I posted my first comment, I hadn't registered that all your cited examples came from the same published source (to which there's *still* no link in the question text). Given that context, I guess I should clarify that my key categorisation of the first example is ***unusual***, rather than ***clumsy*** - and obviously the last three are ***deliberately quirky misuses*** rather than ***mistakes***....

Comment: ... But you might reflect on the fact that searching Google Books for [half a beat of confusion](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22half+a+beat+of+confusion%22) returns precisely ***one*** hit - your cited text. That's pretty "unusual", imho.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I really should have made the reference to that book in my question, instead of simply mentioninig  that I'd found them all in some book. I'm pretty much aware of that unique reference  in Google, because in 99.99% I prefer to google first before asking questions so that to invite somebody to google sth for me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Maybe my surprise of that word usage was not that evident according to my question, but while reading  I stumbled not only once at  it in that context, especially with "**a beat too late**". I searched via "context reverso" for a few more examples, but there were no any at all, then I examined the dictionaries, but didn't find any good examples also, and so then I wrote it down here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I've got your perceptions of these cases ever since your first comment (and that what my post all in all was about!), and just noted where they all have come from, because you might want to know (so I thought).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really just means a quick moment. As @simonatrcl mentioned, it comes from what a beat is defined as in music.

Here it is from Google Dictionary:

> a main accent or rhythmic unit in music or poetry.

It can also be replaced with "bit" or "moment." Here it is with your sentences:

> New York Department of —what? After half a **moment** of confusion, I snatched up the phone. “Hello?”
>
> “Are you saying that things are not okay for you at your grandparents’ home?” said Dave, without missing a **beat**. [can't replace this one; **missing a beat** is also a musical reference]
>
> <..> Dave (who chuckled, but awkwardly, and always a **bit** too late), he liked to laugh <..>
>
> “Oh, ” said Mrs. Barbour, after a **moment** or two of surprise.
>
> “I’m sorry, ” I said, a **moment** too late— <..>